# Bash : adding text from textfile to variable using awk

Tags: bash, variables, text, awk

I am trying to use the values from my textfile in my bash script

```
AantalUsers=$(cat newusers.txt | wc -l) 
echo $AantalUsers
lijstUsername="" 
lijstWachtwoord=""

for ((i = 0 ; i < $AantalUsers ; i++ )); 
do
  lijstUsername=`awk -F" " '{print $1}' test.txt` 
  lijstWachtwoord=`awk -F" " '{print $2}' test.txt` 
done <test.txt 

echo $lijstUsername 
echo $lijstWachtwoord
```

My textfile looks like this :

[image]

This is the output that I get :

[image]

The first list works great but for the second one I only get the last value of the textfile.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: 7
user1 user2 user3
user1pass user2pass user2pass

Comment: As a general piece of advice, it's a lot more useful to us if you post your input/output as plain text inside a code block instead of using screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
     a[i,NR] = $i;
   n = (n < NF ? NF : n)
}
END {
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
     for (j=1; j<=NR; j++)
        printf "%s%s", a[i,j], (j==NR?ORS:OFS)
}' file
```

**Output:**

```
user1 user2 user3
user1pass user2pass user3pass
```

Comment: I still have the same output as before.

Comment: This is copy/paste of output I get from awk. You might have `\r` in your lines. Run `dos2unix` to fix it first.

Comment: Okay I will do that next time. Thanks for the advice